# this.props is not a function - react form

Tags: reactjs, forms, google-maps, state, jsx

I'm trying to use the google maps address autocomplete in an input on my react form.

When I click an address it returns, the state of the input is not updated.

```
import React from "react";
import { Field } from "formik";
/* global google */

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.autocompleteInput = React.createRef();
    this.autocomplete = null;
    this.handlePlaceChanged = this.handlePlaceChanged.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      this.autocompleteInput.current,
      { types: ["address"] }
    );
    this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", this.handlePlaceChanged);
  }


  handlePlaceChanged() {
    const place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    // issue here
    this.props.onPlaceLoaded(place);
    // issue here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Field
        innerRef={this.autocompleteInput}
        id="autocomplete"
        type="text"
        name="address"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder=""
      />
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

How can I update a state to store the selected address?

Edit to show how my Search bar component is being used:

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import SearchBar from "./Google";


const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  fName: Yup.string().required("Please enter your first name"),
  address: Yup.string().required("invalid address"),
});

class Basic extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-12">
            <Formik
              initialValues={{
                fName: "",
                postal: "",
              }}
              validationSchema={LoginSchema}
              onSubmit={(values) => {
                console.log(values);
                console.log("form submitted");
              }}
            >
              {({ touched, errors, isSubmitting, values }) =>
                !isSubmitting ? (
                  <div>
                    <div className="row mb-5">
                      <div className="col-lg-12 text-center">
                        <h1 className="mt-5">LoKnow Form</h1>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <Form>

                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="fName">First Name</label>
                        <Field
                          type="text"
                          name="fName"
                          className={`mt-2 form-control
                    ${touched.fName && errors.fName ? "is-invalid" : ""}`}
                        />

                        <ErrorMessage
                          component="div"
                          name="fName"
                          className="invalid-feedback"
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
                      
<SearchBar />

                        <ErrorMessage
                          component="div"
                          name="address"
                          className="invalid-feedback"
                        />

                      </div>



                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4"
                      >
                        Submit
                      </button>
                    </Form>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div>
                    <h1 className="p-3 mt-5">Form Submitted</h1>

                    <div className="alert alert-success mt-3">
                      Thank for your connecting with us.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )
              }
            </Formik>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Basic;
```

Including more info so stack overflow will let me post

Comment: how's SearchBar used?

Comment: @Federkun Hey thanks for taking a look, I updated the question to include that code

Comment: You didn't pass any props to `SearchBar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

handlePlaceChanged() {
    const place = this.autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
    // issue here
    // this.props.onPlaceLoaded(place);
    // issue here
    Geocode.fromAddress(place).then( response => {
       const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;

       // you need this :
       this.setState({
           place: place,
           lat: lat,
           lng: lng
       });
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error);
  }
);


}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried that code out and it seems to set the state when I click an address, but it removes all the autofilled text from the input. For example if I type "123 Str" and "123 Street Name" is a suggested address, when I click it, the input text flashes "123 Street Name" and then returns to "123 Str". Do I need to declare state in my constructor ? I'm not sure whats going on